# Why my JSON script dont GET a JSONIFY return from FLASK?

Tags: python, html, json, flask, jscript

I have a route in FLASK that return a jsonify object:

```
@app.route('/getgoodbye', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getgoodbye():
    return jsonify({'html':'<h1>Good Bye</h1>'})
```

and a function in jscript that need get this object:

```
    function getgoodbye2(){
        var req = $.getJSON('/getgoodbye');
        alert(req);
    }
```

But the out of alert(req) is: [object Object]

to alert(JSON.stringify(req)): {"readyState":1}

to alert(req.html) is: undefined

How do I can acess the key and values of the dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $.getJSON works async you need to do it inside callback, I have created the JSON in myjson.com (https://api.myjson.com/bins/9ug2k) and here is the code snippet

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/9ug2k',function(resp){
   console.log(resp.html)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Oh! I get something. Thank you very much.